# jdbc: front end java, back end Oracle 10g express edition

Tags: java, oracle10g

I would like to ask for help. I can't connect my java to oracle 10g express edition. I've been trying to fix this issue for about 3 days already. I've already downgraded my javac and java to 1.8 since it is the only available tutorial on youtube on how to resolve this, yet it still don't work. My program does compiles and when i try to run it, my terminal displays "`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character`". I'm using java.swing and not javafx. Please, help me guys im new to this thank you!

```
import java.sql.*;  
class OracleCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  


Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","customer","customer");  


Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  


ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from customer;");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  


con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

Comment: How about showing da code.

Comment: for more info change `System.out.println(e);` to `e.printStackTrace()`  - Also it would be safer to actually select the columns you want rather than `*`

Comment: I tried to change it this happened: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:379)
        at OracleCon.main(OracleCon.java:17)`

Comment: So yeah, maybe better to to actually select your columns.  It looks like there is not three columns

Comment: i tried 'select name from customer' instead of 'select * from customer'. It shows `java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation` when i run it

Comment: `rs.getInt(1)` - do you think that `name` is an `int` ?

Comment: It worked! It actually requires three columns!! Thank you very much!! But i want to ask you how did it happened, like why does java requires three columns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Could you please try this**

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from customer");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString("2")+"  ");  
//1  I removed from your code `rs.getString(3)` and `rs.getString(2)`
//2  You can add string as rs.getString("3"), `rs.getString("2")` like this 
//3 my suggestion is you first remove rs.getString(3) , rs.getString("2") and run
```

**This kind of exception will throw , when it is contained with special chareacters**

> Error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

**This kind of error will thorw  - Most common cause of a misconception that column index**

> Java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! But can i ask you how did it happened? I'm really new to java. I've been studying this all by myself in the past 2 weeks. Please enlighten me thank you!

Comment: Dear , I edited   my answer again  - it will help to understand you and I will attached some links here to understand - https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/javasqlsqlexception-invalid-column.html

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me a lot!

Comment: Someones has given downvote me, I cannot understand why is it,

Comment: I don't understand either, but your suggestion helped me a lot tho. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the semicolon form the sql:

```
select * from customer" instead of "select * from customer;"
```

Comment: my compiler says: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`

Comment: what are the columns in your customer table and what are their data types?

Comment: It only has two entities tho